# How to hold a SQL SUM() query int a Variable

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Good day.
I have an SQL query in C# as shown.

```
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Connection.DatabaseLocationString))
        {
        SQLiteCommand cmd = null;
        string query = 
               String.Format("SELECT  MONTH(SaleDate)  month,
                              SUM(AmountPaid)  sum_amountpaid   
                              FROM {0} 
                              WHERE YEAR(SaleDate) = @1  
                              GROUP BY  MONTH(SaleDate)  ", Sale.TABLE_NAME);
        cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
                  new SQLiteParameter("@1", Properties.Settings.Default.ChartYearlyDisplay));
        con.Open();
        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        con.Close();
        }
```

My challenge is, i have never done nor used a query like this. But what i want to achieve is, i want too Get the value of `SUM(AmountPaid)` for each month, like this.

- January = 20000.00
- Febuary = 18000.00
- March   = 10000.00
  .......and so on.

But i really dont know how too come of that. 
please i need your help, Thanks.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Comment: But what is the problem? Did you try that query? Or you just want to know how to read the returned values?

Comment: Any example of how to use a `SQLiteDataReader` would include how to read the values therein.  What have you tried and what isn't working?  Are you just looking for tutorials on how to read data from a database in C#?

Comment: I read data very well, re-read my question, i said i needed help to read for each month in a year.

Comment: @Steve, Yeah.... I just want to know how to read the returned Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over the returned results using the SQLiteDataReader

```
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader["month"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(reader["sum_amountpaid"].ToString());
}
con.Close();
```

Of course, if you need to return this data, you need a data structure where you can store the results like a `List<T>`

```
// The class where you keep the value for a single month...
public class MonthAmount
{
    public int Month {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
....

// A List where each month of data will be added...
List<MonthAmount> amountData = new List<MonthAmount>();

while(reader.Read())
{
    // Create the instance of MonthAmount for the current month..
    MonthAmount m = new MonthAmount()
    {
          Month = Convert.ToInt32(reader["month"]); 
          Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["sum_amountpaid"]);
    }
    // Add it to the list...
    amountData.Add(m);
}
reader.Close();
// Return the info to the caller....
return amountData;
```

Also according [to SQLite docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), there is no MONTH or YEAR functions available, you should use strftime with an appropriate settings. You could try with

```
string query = $"SELECT  strftime('%', SaleDate)  month,  
                 SUM(AmountPaid)  sum_amountpaid   
                 FROM {Sale.TABLE_NAME}    
                 WHERE strftime('%Y', SaleDate) = @1  
                 GROUP BY strftime('%m', SaleDate)";
```

And if I am not wrong, the result of this strftime function is a string not an integer (IE '03' for March, '2017' for year) so perhaps you should create a parameter with the correct datatype.

Comment: OKay, Thanks Very Much @Steve, I appreciate alot. But it throwing an error `no such function: MONTH` . How do i do that query with SQLite.

Comment: Uhm, that means there is no MONTH function on SQLite. I was looking [here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/MONTH-function-td69588.html) and it seems that you need  strftime('%m', SaleDate) instead of MONTH